# $f = u+iv$ holomorphic on $D(0, 1)$ and $f(0)=0$, prove $\int_{0}^{2\pi}u(e^{it})^{4}dt \leq 36\int_{0}^{2\pi}v(e^{it})^{4}dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

The title says it all, but I'm also to show that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}v(e^{it})^{4}dt \leq 36\int_{0}^{2\pi}u(e^{it})^{4}dt$, which I'm assuming will follow easily.

I have tried using the fact that $f^{4}(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f^{4}(w)}{w-z} dw$ and the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality $(\int fg)^{2} \leq (\int f^{2})(\int g^{2})$ to show some other inequalities, but none were very useful. I know that since $f^{4}$ is holomorphic on the unit sphere since $f$ is as well, its integral over $S^{1}$ will be zero. But using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality doesn't seem to get me anywhere. Any hints? Thank you.

Comment: The integral inequalities in the title and post don't match. Should $u$ be to the power $4$ in the post? And where should the $36$ be?

Comment: @Mattos Sorry about that. I think everything is fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$0=(f(0))^4=\int_{C^+(0,1)}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz=i\int_{0}^{2\pi}( u(e^{it})+iv(e^{it}))^4dt$$ Hence
$$0=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left( u^4(e^{it})+v^4(e^{it})-6u^2(e^{it})v^2(e^{it})\right)dt$$
It follows that
$$\eqalign{\int_{0}^{2\pi}u^4(e^{it})dt +\int_{0}^{2\pi}v^4(e^{it})dt&=6\int_{0}^{2\pi}u^2(e^{it})v^2(e^{it})dt\cr&\le
6 \sqrt{\int_{0}^{2\pi}u^4(e^{it})dt}
\sqrt{\int_{0}^{2\pi}v^4(e^{it})dt}}$$
Now, if $$\eqalign{A&=\min\left(\int_{0}^{2\pi}u^4(e^{it})dt,
\int_{0}^{2\pi}v^4(e^{it})dt\right)\cr
B&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}u^4(e^{it})dt+
\int_{0}^{2\pi}v^4(e^{it})dt}$$ 
then we conclude from the above inequality $B\le 6\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A}$,and consequently $B\le 36 A$, that is
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}u^4(e^{it})dt+
\int_{0}^{2\pi}v^4(e^{it})dt\le 36\min\left(\int_{0}^{2\pi}u^4(e^{it})dt,
\int_{0}^{2\pi}v^4(e^{it})dt\right)$$
This implies both desired inequalities.

Comment: I only needed a hint, but thank you for the solution!